# Is there any string function in php to add multiple random chars to addcslashes()?

Tags: php

```
$str = "Welcome to my humble Homepage!";

$str=addcslashes($str,'m');
$str=addcslashes($str,'W');
$str=addcslashes($str,'t');

echo addcslashes($str,'H')."<br>";
```

*I do this way....Is there any other function to escape multiple random characters?*

Comment: Vague guess: `$str = preg_replace('/([mWtH])/', '\\$1', $str)`

Comment: I don't see any random characters in your code. What random characters?

Comment: @eis **random char set: 'm','W','t','H'**  I add char slash to every single character i need and assign it $str

Comment: -1 - apparent misuse of "random"

Comment: random in the sense i choose "single char set of my choice" apart from choosing "range of characters"...if it makes no sense suggest me an edit..thank you..

Comment: I agree, he's looking for the syntax to select arbitrary (random choice) characters as opposed to an incremental range of characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = "Welcome to my humble Homepage!";

echo addcslashes($str,'m.W.t.H')."<br>";
```